# How can I debug sub-process in vscode?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, subprocess, spawn

I am using `execa` to spawn a sub-process in index.js, but I can't debug the spawned file(log_ok.js). this is the code, does anyone know how to debug it?

index.js

```
const execa = require('execa');

execa('node', ['./log_ok.js'], { stdio: 'inherit' })
```

and my launch.json:

```
{
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "debug",
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}/index.js",
      "autoAttachChildProcesses": true
    }
```

./log_ok.js

```
console.log('ok')
```

Answer (score 0):

you maybe try a "attach" request (see https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/debugging#_launch-versus-attach-configurations), and execa the sub process with an inspect port